# Trying to get params from list in joomla

Tags: joomla, module

I have a joomla 3 module. It works great. I want to add parameters in the administration section that I can then use in the `tmpl->default.php` file, but I'm struggling to find out how to do it.

I have in my XML file:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field
            name="show_category"
            type="list"
            label="What to display"
            description="What to display"
            default="">
                <option value="0">Day/Time/Event</option>
                <option value="1">Day/Time/Event/Description</option>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

and then in my `default.php` file:

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;

    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_calendar_ajax_google');
    $moduleParams = new JRegistry();
    $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
    $param = $moduleParams->get('show_category', '');

    $dashboardID =  $param['show_category'];
```

but is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better not to call params directly in default.php file rather you can call params in your mod_calendar_ajax_google.php file like this

```
$category = $params->get('show_category','Day/Time/Event');
```

This will give the name if it is set in your options, else it gives the default value `Day/Time/Event`.

To call it in your default.php file, you can directly call $category. Hope I made myself clear.

If at all you need to call param directly from anywhere in joomla you need to remove last line. It should only be this

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_calendar_ajax_google');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
$dashboardID = $moduleParams->get('show_category', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:
You have module "mod_calendar_ajax_google". Then you need next files structure:

-mod_calendar_ajax_google.xml

-mod_calendar_ajax_google.php

-helper.php

-tmpl (folder)

--default.php

Code mod_calendar_ajax_google.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php';
$data = modCalendarAjaxGoogleHelper::getData($params);

require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_calendar_ajax_google', $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

Code helper.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class modCalendarAjaxGoogleHelper {

    public static function getData(&$params) {

        $data = $params->get('show_category');

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Code default.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

print_r ($data); // <-- YOUR PARAMS
```